# Android: Media Player stop after seconds

Tags: android, media-player

I use this code for stream video

But after 5-6 seconds , player stop

If i use mp4 format for this , working correct

But use stream URL stop after seconds

```
public static SurfaceView    videoSurface = null;
public SurfaceHolder         videoHolder  = null;
public static MediaPlayer    mediaPlayer;

new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mediaPlayer = null;
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(this, PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDisplay(videoHolder);
            String file = "http://test.com/file.m3u8";
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();  
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener((OnPreparedListener) this);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
         mediaPlayer.start();
     }
}).start();
```

How can fix it ?

> Logcat :

```
08-11 18:42:21.370: V/MediaPlayer(6060): callback application
08-11 18:42:21.370: V/MediaPlayer(6060): back from callback
08-11 18:42:21.370: I/MediaPlayer(6060): Info (702,0)
08-11 18:42:21.370: I/MediaPlayer(6060): Info (3,0)
08-11 18:42:46.835: V/MediaPlayer(6060): message received msg=200, ext1=701, ext2=0
08-11 18:42:46.835: W/MediaPlayer(6060): info/warning (701, 0)
08-11 18:42:46.835: V/MediaPlayer(6060): callback application
08-11 18:42:46.835: V/MediaPlayer(6060): back from callback
08-11 18:42:46.840: I/MediaPlayer(6060): Info (701,0)
08-11 18:42:46.940: V/MediaPlayer(6060): message received msg=2, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-11 18:42:46.940: V/MediaPlayer(6060): playback complete
08-11 18:42:46.940: V/MediaPlayer(6060): callback application
08-11 18:42:46.940: V/MediaPlayer(6060): back from callback
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it works well with local file the only reason IMO is an actual playlist `http://test.com/file.m3u8`. Probably there some issues with that file or streaming server settings.

Comment: Add log cat to first post

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the file format, android media player does not support this file format, check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)